# Deleting multiple files and folders using Ansible

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, jenkins-groovy

I need to delete files and folders using a ansible playbook. I pass the file/foler paths as a variable to an Ansible playbook from a Groovy script.
Variables are in a *properties* file named *delete.properties*. I stored file/foler paths seperatly in a variables so I can change the paths as I need in future.

*delete.properties*:

```
delete_files=/home/new-user/myfolder/dltfolder1 /home/new-user/myfolder/dltfolder2 /home/new-user/myfolder/dltfolder3
```

Groovy script:

```
     stage("Read variable"){
      steps{
        script{
         def propertifile = readFile(properti file path)
         deleteParams = new Properties()
         deleteParams.load(new StringReader(propertifile))
        }
     }
  }
    stage("Delete files/folders"){
      steps{
        script{
         sh script: """cd ansible code path && \
         export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False && \
         ansible-playbook delete.yml \ 
         --extra-vars"dete_files=${deleteParams.delete_files}" --user user"""
        }
     }
  }
```

Ansible playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: delete files
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: delete files
     file:
      path: "{{ delete_files }}"
      state: absent
```

As a result of above codes, only the first file path in `delete_files` (*/home/new-user/myfolder/dltfolder1*) variable in *delete.properties* file gets deleted.

I need to delete the other file/folder paths included in the `delete_files` variable too.

Comment: You do have at least two issues: first (on Ansible point of view): the files module won't be able to delete files without a loop. Second (but maybe the more important for you): `--extra-vars"dete_files=${deleteParams.delete_files}"` will render as `--extra-vars"delete_files=a b c"`, and will end up `delete_files == 'a'`, because the k=v won't cope with those spaces.

Comment: Stupid question: why do you want to pass that as `extra-vars`? Why not read the file from the Ansible playbook?

Comment: The extra variable `dete_files` is not used in your playbook. [edit] the question and make it [mre]. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and asked to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the path of the file into the extra vars. For example,

```bash
         sh script: """cd ansible code path && \
         export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False && \
         ansible-playbook delete.yml \ 
         --extra-vars "dete_files=/tmp/delete.properties" --user user"""
```

Then, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── f1
├── f2
└── f3
```

, the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/delete.properties 
delete_files=/tmp/test/f1 /tmp/test/f2 /tmp/test/f3
```

, and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat delete.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    delete_files: "{{ lookup('ini',
                             'delete_files',
                             file=dete_files,
                             type='properties') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: delete_files

    - name: delete files
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ delete_files.split() }}"
```

gives, running in *--check --diff* mode

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars "dete_files=/tmp/delete.properties" -CD

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  delete_files: /tmp/test/f1 /tmp/test/f2 /tmp/test/f3

TASK [delete files] **************************************************************************
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,5 +1,2 @@
 path: /tmp/test/f1
-path_content:
-  directories: []
-  files: []
-state: directory
+state: absent

changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/f1)
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,5 +1,2 @@
 path: /tmp/test/f2
-path_content:
-  directories: []
-  files: []
-state: directory
+state: absent

changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/f2)
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,5 +1,2 @@
 path: /tmp/test/f3
-path_content:
-  directories: []
-  files: []
-state: directory
+state: absent

changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/f3)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This does the same thing that my script does. Deletes the first folder defined in variable. Doesn't delete the folder/file paths after the first one

Comment: The output clearly shows that all folders /tmp/test/f1, f2, and f3 will be deleted in the iteration `loop: "{{ delete_files.split() }}"`. Run your playbook in `--check --diff mode` and post the details.

Comment: This works. Issue was in how I gave the filepaths to variable in properties file. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to parse the *properties* file inside the Ansible playbook, with a [`ini` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_lookup.html), if you are indeed acting on `localhost`, as you are showing it in your playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      loop: >-
        {{
          lookup(
            'ini',
            'delete_files type=properties file=delete.properties'
          ).split()
        }}
```